# How to Crop a 3D model with a 3D model?

Tags: 3d, mesh, 3d-modelling, 3d-model

If i have two models M1 and M2, how do i do so when M2 is inside M1 it will crop M1?

I was thinking on remove all verticles in M1 that are inside M2 and then copy all verticles in M2 that are inside M1 to M1.

But this obviously leads to problems.

So how do i do this in a easy way that still gives a good result?

Comment: Are you refering to CSG (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry) ?

Comment: Please specify whar do you intend for model, a triangular mesh?